# Delete selected checkbox ticked rows

Tags: database, jsp, checkbox

I am new on jsp. I am providing the checkboxes in front of every row that are being fetched from DB. Now I want to delete the rows whose checkboxes have been checked.
Please suggest how to achieve this task on submit of form.
I can make the delete query at my end but issue is with check boxes ticked or not ticket approach.
Do we have any way as `request.getParameter("delete_checkbox").value` or something like this?

Answer (score 2):

This is what you need :

http://theopentutorials.com/examples/java-ee/servlet/getting-checkbox-values-from-html-form-in-servlet/

As shown in the tutorial in value `attribute` pass the Id of your records.

Parse them to Long in servlet and make a server hit to `delete`.